# Visual Studio, seeing the optimized "release mode" asm in the Disassembly window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, assembly, x86

I can see the asm of a C++ project (32-bit) in the Disassembly window of Visual Studio 2012 fairly easily. However, I want to see the same code where the compiler has inlined a function and therefore I wanted to put a break point in the Release mode. However, when I change the settings in Release mode so that Debug Information Format is "Program database for Edit and Continue" when I run the code it does not break.

(I did output the asm file but the code did not look anything like what I was expecting. The Disassembly window seems to provide a better view).

This was the code I was running with:

```
int my_func(int m, int n){
    int r= 0;
    r= m*n;
    return r;
}

int main(){
    int u = my_func(1,3);
    std::cout << u << std::endl;    //I put a breakpoint here but it doesnt work
    return 1;
}
```

So, I wanted to put a breakpoint in the above code so that I could see the asm produced after the compiler had inlined `my_func()`.

UPDATE: I also tried the answer to this Q but it didnt work:

[What's the best way to view accurate disassembly in VC++ 2010 while in Win32 Release mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059614/whats-the-best-way-to-view-accurate-disassembly-in-vc-2010-while-in-win32-rel)

> Build symbols for your release build (/Zi) [edit: and link with
>   /DEBUG] and you'll be able to set breakpoints.

UPDATE2: "Debugable assembly" linker flag also doesnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: Your question title doesn't line up very well with the question you're actually asking. Your code isn't a complete, runnable example along with the compiler and linker flags you've set. I built the code you've shown in Release mode for x86 with /Zi /Ox, and it breaks in the debugger just fine. If I choose Go to Disassembly from the context menu, then what I see is that the compiler has replaced your call to my_func with a push of a literal 3.

Optimized code may eliminate function calls, or substitute equivalent code from elsewhere in your project. Breakpoints may behave oddly as a result.