# Plain C++ Code 10 times faster than inline assembler. Why?

Tags: c++, performance, assembly

These two code snippets do the same thing: Adding two float arrays together and storing the result back into them.

Inline Assembler:

```
void vecAdd_SSE(float* v1, float* v2) { 
    _asm {
        mov esi, v1
        mov edi, v2
        movups xmm0, [esi]
        movups xmm1, [edi]
        addps xmm0, xmm1
        movups [esi], xmm0
        movups [edi], xmm0
    }
}
```

Plain C++ Code:

```
void vecAdd_Std(float* v1, float* v2) {
    v1[0] = v1[0]+ v2[0];
    v1[1] = v1[1]+ v2[1];
    v1[2] = v1[2]+ v2[2];
    v1[3] = v1[3]+ v2[3];

    v2[0] = v1[0];
    v2[1] = v1[1];
    v2[2] = v1[2];
    v2[3] = v1[3];
}
```

Disassembly for C++ Code (Disassembly made in Debug mode because i cannot view the Disassembly in Release mode for some reason):

```
 void vecAdd_Std(float* v1, float* v2) {
 push        ebp  
 mov         ebp,esp  
 sub         esp,0C0h  
 push        ebx  
 push        esi  
 push        edi  
 lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
 mov         ecx,30h  
 mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
 rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  

    v1[0] = v1[0]+ v2[0];
 mov         eax,4  
 imul        ecx,eax,0  
 mov         edx,4  
 imul        eax,edx,0  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [v1]  
 mov         esi,dword ptr [v2]  
 movss       xmm0,dword ptr [edx+ecx]  
 addss       xmm0,dword ptr [esi+eax]  
 mov         eax,4  
 imul        ecx,eax,0  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [v1]  
 movss       dword ptr [edx+ecx],xmm0  
    v1[1] = v1[1]+ v2[1];
 mov         eax,4  
 shl         eax,0  
    v1[1] = v1[1]+ v2[1];
 mov         ecx,4  
 shl         ecx,0  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [v1]  
 mov         esi,dword ptr [v2]  
 movss       xmm0,dword ptr [edx+eax]  
 addss       xmm0,dword ptr [esi+ecx]  
 mov         eax,4  
 shl         eax,0  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [v1]  
 movss       dword ptr [ecx+eax],xmm0  
    v1[2] = v1[2]+ v2[2];
 mov         eax,4  
 shl         eax,1  
 mov         ecx,4  
 shl         ecx,1  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [v1]  
 mov         esi,dword ptr [v2]  
 movss       xmm0,dword ptr [edx+eax]  
 addss       xmm0,dword ptr [esi+ecx]  
 mov         eax,4  
 shl         eax,1  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [v1]  
 movss       dword ptr [ecx+eax],xmm0  
    v1[3] = v1[3]+ v2[3];
 mov         eax,4  
 imul        ecx,eax,3  
 mov         edx,4  
 imul        eax,edx,3  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [v1]  
 mov         esi,dword ptr [v2]  
 movss       xmm0,dword ptr [edx+ecx]  
 addss       xmm0,dword ptr [esi+eax]  
 mov         eax,4  
 imul        ecx,eax,3  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [v1]  
 movss       dword ptr [edx+ecx],xmm0  

    v2[0] = v1[0];
 mov         eax,4  
 imul        ecx,eax,0  
 mov         edx,4  
 imul        eax,edx,0  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [v2]  
 mov         esi,dword ptr [v1]  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [esi+ecx]  
 mov         dword ptr [edx+eax],ecx  
    v2[1] = v1[1];
 mov         eax,4  
 shl         eax,0  
 mov         ecx,4  
 shl         ecx,0  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [v2]  
 mov         esi,dword ptr [v1]  
 mov         eax,dword ptr [esi+eax]  
 mov         dword ptr [edx+ecx],eax  
    v2[2] = v1[2];
 mov         eax,4  
 shl         eax,1  
 mov         ecx,4  
 shl         ecx,1  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [v2]  
 mov         esi,dword ptr [v1]  
 mov         eax,dword ptr [esi+eax]  
 mov         dword ptr [edx+ecx],eax  
    v2[3] = v1[3];
 mov         eax,4  
 imul        ecx,eax,3  
 mov         edx,4  
 imul        eax,edx,3  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [v2]  
 mov         esi,dword ptr [v1]  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [esi+ecx]  
 mov         dword ptr [edx+eax],ecx  

}
```

Now I made a time measurement on those to functions and noticed that the inline assembler code takes approximately 10 times longer (in Release mode).
Does anybody know why?

Comment: Can you show the disassembly of the C++ code for comparison?

Comment: Also specify what compiler you are using. (looks like VC++?)

Comment: How did you measure?

Comment: That disassembly is definitely not release mode!

Comment: @BoPersson Yes I don't know how to output the disassembly for release mode.

Comment: @AlanStokes I measured by using Windows QueryPerformanceCounter

Comment: @BoPersson Yes I do use them. I output  them with cout.(After the time measurement)

Comment: Is the data aligned properly ?  ah movups is for unaligned data.. answer my own question...

Comment: @BoPersson It makes no difference: if i use movaps and aligned float array there is no difference in performance

Comment: ref: getting the real disassembly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059614/whats-the-best-way-to-view-accurate-disassembly-in-vc-2010-while-in-win32-rel maybe? and go from there

Comment: @JCx if i try to set  __debugbreak()  in the function the code stops outside of the function, so i cannot see the disassembly of this particular funtion

Comment: Set it way before and step through?

Comment: Build with `/FAsc` and look at the `.cod` file produced to see the assembly code.

Comment: The code was probably inlined unrecognizably into the calling function.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but why does your inline assembly not appear to factor in anywhere that the float arrays are size 4? It is clear that the compiled assembler is doing this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On my machine (VS2015 64-bit mode), the compiler inlines `vecAdd_Std` and produces

```
00007FF625921C8F  vmovups     xmm1,xmmword ptr [__xmm@4100000040c000004080000040000000 (07FF625929D60h)]  
00007FF625921C97  vmovups     xmm4,xmm1  
00007FF625921C9B  vcvtss2sd   xmm1,xmm1,xmm4
```

Test code

```
int main() {
    float x[4] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    float y[4] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

    vecAdd_Std(x, y);

    std::cout << x[0];
}
```

Comment: Ok that answers my question. And now it is clear why i cannot set a breakpoint in this function. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: That's cheating, you are using the same float vector twice thereby removing one memory load :)

Comment: @Cross_ - This wasn't meant to be a "fair benchmark", but to show that Philinator's disassembly isn't even close to what the compiler produces in release mode. And that "hand optimized" assembly isn't automagically the best code you can get.

Comment: @Philinator: You could set a breakpoint by compiling the function in a separate translation unit and linking int he object file.  Then again, much of the performance difference between the compiled C and hand-written assembly might go away as well.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't really calling a function that executes *one* SSE instruction, are you? There's non-trivial overhead involved in setting up the xmm registers, and you're copying the values from memory to the registers and back, which will take far longer than the actual calculation.

I wouldn't be at all surprised to find that the compiler inlines the C++ version of the function, but doesn't (can't, really) do the same for functions that contain inline assembly.