# Is leaq THAT slow or there is another reason smaller assembly listing is slower than the longer one?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, intel

I do not know any real assembly, but can read GCC `-S` output to evaluate actual costs of given C code.

This question is not that much about profiling and benchmarks, but rather educational. I need someone to explain me why [1] snippet is not faster than the second one.

Well, used to think like: "yeah, some operations like MUL are pretty expensive, but if one assembly is X times bigger than another, it should be slower".

This was quite true until I have met those two:

```
unsigned char bytes[4] = {0, 0, 0, 5};

// 1
int32_t val = *((int32_t*)bytes);      
/* produces:
        leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax
        movl    (%rax), %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        movl    $0, %eax
*/

// 2   
val = bytes[3] |                               
      (bytes[2] << 8) |                        
      (bytes[1] << 16) |
      (bytes[0] << 24);
/* produces: 
        movzbl  -13(%rbp), %eax
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        movzbl  -14(%rbp), %edx
        movzbl  %dl, %edx
        sall    $8, %edx
        orl     %eax, %edx
        movzbl  -15(%rbp), %eax
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        sall    $16, %eax
        orl     %eax, %edx
        movzbl  -16(%rbp), %eax
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        sall    $24, %eax
        orl     %edx, %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        movl    $0, %eax
*/
```

And benchmarks are showing that the 2-nd one is 5-10% faster.
What is going on here?

The only significant difference and "reason" I can imagine is `LEAQ` is something very slow.
Last 2 lines are identical, so maybe `MOV` price is so high that 1 extra `MOV` is worse than tons of instructions.

Here is what I used to measure execution times:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define REPETITIONS 32
#define ITERATIONS 90000

#define CODE1                   \
  for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {    \
    val = *((int32_t*)bytes);           \
  }

#define CODE2                   \
  for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {    \
    val = bytes[3] |                \
      (bytes[2] << 8) |             \
      (bytes[1] << 16) |            \
      (bytes[0] << 24);             \
  }

int main(void) {
  clock_t minTs = 999999999, ts;
  unsigned char bytes[4] = {0, 0, 0, 5};    
  int32_t val;                  

  for (int i = 0; i < REPETITIONS; ++i) {
    ts = clock();

    CODE1; // Or CODE2

    ts = clock() - ts;
    if (ts < minTs) minTs = ts;
  }

  printf("ts: %ld\n", minTs);

  return val;
}
```

---

*Update*:
as it turns out, results are hardware specific, so while [1] is slower on my laptop (x64 i5-4260U), it is faster on my PC (but by a very small fraction like 5%).

Comment: I tested your code to measure time and the results for `CODE1` are oscillating, in the range of `522 <= x <= 670`.

Comment: Apart from the first version possibly invoking undefined behaviour due to missalignment and being implementation defined (endianess)? Well , your basic assumption is just wrong. The length of assembler code is a very weak measure for the execution time. There are many more factors involved and I'm afraid you have to learn assembler and the internals of the **specific** CPU to make qualified assumptions.

Comment: Endianess is not a problem because the bytes are prepared by another routine which knows what order machine has and puts bytes in correct order (for later quick decoding). Also, in a target application i used int32_t, so I guess no troubles with missalignment, or I am wrong?

Comment: Updated snippets to reflect the actual types being used.

Comment: There is definitely no way that the first version is *really* slower than the second one: The first one instructs the CPU to do precisely what's needed, nothing more. That you saw the second version outperforming the first one must have been a measurement error. Repeat your measurement ten times, and you will likely see that neither version is consistently faster.

Comment: @Olaf The first version is also an aliasing violation.  Anyway, since `val` is not actually used within the loop, who knows what the optimizer is doing?

Comment: @cmaster: It can, because some CPUs add quite some penalties for missaligned accesses.

Comment: Are you timing unoptimized code?  If you turn on optimizations most of this code is simply discarded by gcc, clang, and msvc. The assembly and timings might look very different if you had a better micro-benchmark.

Comment: -O0. No optimizations should take place.

Comment: Oh, then this isn't very interesting.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: As the compiler has to generate correct machine code from correct source code, it is acceptable it it optimizes to a single load. The standard does only define an abstract machine, not how the compiler might optimize.

Comment: @cmaster test was executed more than 30 times.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about benchmarking without optimizations. Totally uninteresting!

Comment: This question is not about optimizations but rather about curiosity.

Comment: There must be some **objective** reasons why [1] snippet can not perform much better than [2] and Olaf already gave some.

Comment: @Olaf I am fully aware of the alignment issue, and if you look closely, you find that both the load and the store are perfectly aligned in the first assembler listing. So, definitely no penalty for misalignement.

Comment: @BoPersson actually, I am so tired to see something like "turn on the optimizations" or "premature optimizations is a root of all evil". Look at the question title. It asks for explanation, and turning on the optimizations is NOT an explanation.

Comment: @IskanderSharipov: But you are asking a performance question and compiler optimizations are important if you want to take advantage of modern processors. The difference it makes can be non-intuitive and quite dramatic. I think it's a mistake to ignore what your tools can do.

Comment: @IskanderSharipov In that case, there is some other effect taking place here. As I said, it is not imaginable that the assembler code in the first listing takes less time than the assembler code in the second one. Also `90000` iterations are not nearly enough to get solid numbers, that's less than a millisecond. Interruptions by the kernel can cost the running process in the range between 10 and 200 microseconds. I'd add at least three zeros to the iteration count, better four, so that a single repetition takes at least a second. With lower counts, you simply can't trust your numbers.

Comment: @cmaster I tried the different numbers. For 9000000 iterations and 100 repetitions (we take min from execution time of 100 runs) [1]:`45027` [2]:`40813`. This impresses me. Results are pretty stable.

@Blastfurnace I really do not know what to say. I got strange results from benchmark and wanted an guru answer explaining them, thats all about it.

Comment: Also, I find asking questions  on SO a little too stressful. It is nearly impossible for a non-expert to ask question properly, but not only expert questions need answering. Usually we do not even fully know what exactly is the root of problem and can describe only visible top of it. There is nothing wrong about this in my opinion. In this situation the most visible "case" is 4 vs 16 instructions (take out the same last 2 and we have 2 vs 14), where 14 instructions outperform those 2...

Comment: @IskanderSharipov: It's not a terrible question but the answer is hardware dependent and the difference is relatively small in this case. I wouldn't start looking at the assembly until after optimizations are enabled and profiling points to a specific hot spot. Not to mention that modern CPUs are complex enough that it can be difficult to reason about how your code is executed.

Comment: @IskanderSharipov - And I still think it is **totally** uninteresting how fast unoptimized code runs, because that information is not useful in the real world. And we end up with questions like this [Plain C++ code 10 times faster than inline assembler. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385696/plain-c-code-10-times-faster-than-inline-assembler-why) *Oh, you ran it optimized but looked at debug code...*.

Comment: @BoPersson: At least in this case it's clear from the start that he's asking "why is this asm sequence faster than this other asm sequence"?  **Not** "Why is C faster than asm?".  It's a valid question even if the asm sequences came from a compiler at `-O0`

Comment: @cmaster: I was surprised too, but the first version really is slightly slower on my SnB CPU.  I still don't know why, but it's not very interesting to find out, because the bottleneck something you'd only get from a non-optimizing compiler.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: It's not *that* hard to find the major bottlenecks.  You're right about the subtle stuff.  It's not hard to see why they both run at about the same speed from the asm, but the slight diff is weird.  Anyway, I just updated my answer with what the OP should have done to see optimizing compiler output (put it in a function that's not `inline` or `static`, so the compiler has to make a stand-alone version that works for any data input.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: **extra loads/stores can reduce store-forwarding latency on Sandybridge-family**, so the extra work in CODE2 probably sped up the loop-carried dependency chain that both loops bottleneck on.  (**Because `-O0` keeps the loop counter in memory**).

This effect is [present in all SnB-family CPUs](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/12/03/intel-i7-loop-performance-anomaly/), including the Sandybridge I had when writing this answer, the OP's Haswell, the Broadwell in [Adding a redundant assignment speeds up code when compiled without optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189685/adding-a-redundant-assignment-speeds-up-code-when-compiled-without-optimization), and the Skylake in [Loop with function call faster than an empty loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442458/loop-with-function-call-faster-than-an-empty-loop/45529487).

---

#### what you should have done

If you're curious about how your code compiles to asm, put your code in a function where it can't get optimized away.  On [this godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/g/fyItL8), you can see how gcc 5.1 and newer (at `-O3 -march=native -mtune=native`) sees through the ORing together of bytes and uses `movbe` (move big-endian) to bwap on the fly while loading.  icc, clang, and older gcc emit instructions that load individual bytes and shift / OR them into place.

I was disappointed that compilers didn't see through the ORing of bytes even when I reversed the order to do a little-endian load instead of a big-endian load.  (see the native, big, and little endian functions on godbolt.)  Even changing the types to uint32_t and uint8_t didn't help for compilers other than gcc >= 5.1.

Obviously with optimization on, compilers throw away the loops that just set an unused variable.  They just call `clock` twice, printf, and then mov-immediate the answer into `eax`.  If you want to actually benchmark something, compile it separately from the function that will call it with constant data.  That way, you can have simple code that takes its work as function arguments, and it can't get inlined into the caller that passes it constant data.

Also, gcc treats `main` as a "cold" function, and doesn't optimize it quite as heavily as normal functions.  In most programs, `main` doesn't contain the inner loop.

---

#### Why is the `-O0` asm so slow?

**Obviously the code is horrible** from `-O0`, storing to memory, and even incrementing the loop counter *in memory*.  It's still somewhat interesting to figure out why it's running even slower than I'd expect, CODE1 at under one insn per clock.

You didn't show the whole loop for either piece of code.  Probably removing the loop body would still leave a slow loop.  I think the loop itself is the problem, and is so inefficient that there's time for the CPU to do all the extra instructions in CODE2 without seeing any slowdown.

---

**TL;DR**: both loops are bottlenecked by the `add $1, -0x24(%rbp)`, which increments the loop counter in memory.  6 cycle latency in a loop-carried dependency chain explains why both loops are bottlenecked to the same speed.

I don't know exactly why the extra instructions in CODE2 somehow help get closer to the 6 cycles per iteration theoretical max, but this isn't a bottleneck that should ever come up in code that anyone would ever write.  Keep your loop counters in registers, and don't put include a read-modify-write instruction of the same address in a loop-carried dependency chain.  ([incrementing memory at different addresses each iteration is fine, e.g. for CountingSort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32664104/224132).)

---

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/fyItL8) for the changes I made to the code.  (With ITERATIONS bumped up by a factor of 100 so runtime dominates the noise of startup overhead.)  That link has optimization enabled, for the benefit of the first 3 functions.

godbolt doesn't have a C mode, only C++, and I got a less-bad loop from gcc 4.9.2 locally than godbolt shows.  (g++ implements a `for(){}` loop exactly as written, with a cmp/jcc at the top, and a jmp at the bottom.  gcc even at `-O0` uses a `do{} while(count++ < ITERATIONS);` structure, with just a cmp/jle at the bottom.

> I do not know any real assembly, but can read GCC -S output to
>   evaluate actual costs of given C code.
>
> Well, used to think like: "yeah, some operations like MUL are pretty
>   expensive, but if one assembly is X times bigger than another, it
>   should be slower".

The first thing to look for is throughput and latency bottlenecks.  On Intel, that means 4 uops per clock throughput, or less if a long dependency chain is a limit.  Then there's per-execution-port bottlenecks.  E.g. two memory ops per clock, with at most one of them being a store.  At most one `mul` per clock, because only one of the 3 ALU ports has an integer multiplier.

See [Agner Fog's site](http://agner.org/optimize/) for optimization guides, micro-architecture docs, and tables of instruction latency/throughputs / uops / ports they can run on.

Your loops are badly bottlenecked by keeping the loop counter in memory.  On SandyBridge (my sytem) and Haswell (yours), Agner Fog's table has the latency of `add` with a memory destination at 6 clocks.  There's no way it can run any faster than one iteration per 6 clocks per iteration.  With 6 instructions in the loop, that's 1 insn per cycle.

In practice, I'm getting less throughput than that.  Maybe the store as part of `add`'s read-modify-write operation is sometimes delayed by the other loads/stores in the loop.  IDK why CODE2 is slightly faster, that is strange.  Maybe it orders things differently so the loop-carried-dependency `add` is delayed less often.

The loop *body* using `lea` and a 32bit load is obviously faster.  IDK why you think it's the `lea` that's slow.

It's not an an alignment / uop-cache issue.  The loop should stream from the loop buffer either way, even if there were more than 18 uops in a 32B block of code (meaning it couldn't go in the uop cache).  Frontend bottlenecks (other than branch mispredicts, which we don't have) can't be an issue when our insns per clock are so low.  The frontend can easily keep a big supply of uops queued up for the scheduler to dispatch.

From `perf report`, profiling clocks taken on each instruction: CODE1's inner loop.  Counts aren't cycle-accurate.  We're probably seeing the CPU stuck on the instructions right *after* the `add $1, mem`, which I'm sure is the bottleneck loop-carried dependency.  It needs to forward the store to the load on the next iteration, which still takes 6 clocks.

```
   ###### CODE1 inner loop, profiling on cycles
 13.97 │400680:   lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
       │400684:   mov    (%rax),%eax
       │400686:   mov    %eax,-0x2c(%rbp)
       │400689:   addl   $0x1,-0x24(%rbp)
 13.84 │40068d:   cmpl   $0x89543f,-0x24(%rbp)
 72.19 │400694: ↑ jle    400680 <code1+0x4a>
       ## end of the loop
        400696:   callq  4004e0 <clock@plt>
        40069b:   sub    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
```

```
       #CODE2
 15.08 │400738:   movzbl -0xd(%rbp),%eax
  0.88 │40073c:   movzbl %al,%eax
  0.05 │40073f:   movzbl -0xe(%rbp),%edx
       │400743:   movzbl %dl,%edx
 13.91 │400746:   shl    $0x8,%edx
  0.70 │400749:   or     %eax,%edx
  0.05 │40074b:   movzbl -0xf(%rbp),%eax
       │40074f:   movzbl %al,%eax
 12.70 │400752:   shl    $0x10,%eax
  0.60 │400755:   or     %eax,%edx
  0.09 │400757:   movzbl -0x10(%rbp),%eax
  0.05 │40075b:   movzbl %al,%eax
 13.03 │40075e:   shl    $0x18,%eax
  0.70 │400761:   or     %edx,%eax
  0.14 │400763:   mov    %eax,-0x2c(%rbp)
  0.09 │400766:   addl   $0x1,-0x24(%rbp)
 13.63 │40076a:   cmpl   $0x89543f,-0x24(%rbp)
 28.29 │400771: ↑ jle    400738 <code2+0x4a>
     ## end of the loop
        400773: → callq  4004e0 <clock@plt>
        400778:   sub    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
```

Wow, that's pretty hilarious.  gcc does a redundant `movzbl %al, %eax` after loading `%eax` from an 8bit memory location with `movzbl`.

So in 6 clocks per iteration, can the CPU handle all that busy-work of loading an combining bytes?  Yes.

- 4x `movzx reg, mem`: 4 load-port uops.  (p2/p3)
- 4x `movzx reg, reg`: 4 uops for any ALU port (p015)
- 3x `shl   reg, imm`: 3 uops for ALU ports p0/p5
- 3x `or    reg, reg`: 3 uops for any ALU port (p015)
- 1x `mov   mem, reg`: 1 uop fused-domain: 1 store-data (p4), 1 store-address (p23)
- 1x `add   mem, imm`: 2 fused-domain.  unfused: 1 ALU uop (p015), 1 load uop (p23), 1 store-data (p4), 1 store-address (p23)
- 1x `cmp   mem, imm`: 1 uop for p015, 1 for p23.
- 1x `jle`:  1 uop for p5.  (can't macro-fuse with the cmp, because of imm and mem)

total fused-domain uops: 4+4+3+3+1+2+1+1 = 19.  That fits in the 28uop loop stream buffer, avoiding any possiblity of uop-cache bottlenecks, and can issue in 5 clocks.  (At 4 per cycle, with the last cycle issuing only 3).

load uops: 4 + 1 + 1 = 6.  store uops: 2.

ALU uops: 4+3+3+1+1+1 = 13.  SnB's 3 ALU uop ports can handle that in 4.33 clocks.  Most of the uops can run on any port, so no one port is a bottleneck.  (Haswell has a 4th ALU port, p6.  It has an even easier time.  But ALU uops aren't the bottleneck.)

The latency of the loop bodies don't matter, because the next iteration doesn't read any result.  Each iteration reads some data and stores it, independently of what the previous iteration did.  Many loops are like this.  It's usual for such loops to load from and store to a different address each time, but the CPU just does what it's told.

Anyway, even if the dependency chain within each loop takes more than 6 clocks, work from multiple iterations can be in flight.  Nothing in one iteration has to wait for the previous, *except* the loop-counter increment with a memory destination.

So all that work in the CODE2 loop is not a bottleneck at all.

For SnB/HSW, add-immediate with a memory destination is 2 uops, while inc on a memory destination is 3, according to Agner Fog's table, which is strange.  I wonder if that's an error, or if Intel CPUs really are slower when using `inc` on a memory destination instead of `add $1`?

---

Test timings (from gcc 4.9.2).  I don't see anything obvious that would explain why CODE2 gets closer to the theoretical max of one iteration per 6 clocks.  My only guess is that CODE1 is confused by the `call` right after the `jle`, but CODE1 isn't?  Maybe a perf record on uops

Sandybridge i5 (2500k):

```
## CODE1 ##
 Performance counter stats for './a.out 1' (4 runs):

        589.117019      task-clock (msec)         #    0.999 CPUs utilized            ( +-  1.30% )
     2,068,118,847      cycles                    #    3.511 GHz                      ( +-  0.48% )
     1,729,505,746      instructions              #    0.84  insns per cycle        
                                                  #    0.86  stalled cycles per insn  ( +-  0.01% )
     2,018,533,639      uops_issued_any           # 3426.371 M/sec                    ( +-  0.02% )
     5,648,003,370      uops_dispatched_thread    # 9587.235 M/sec                    ( +-  2.51% )
     3,170,497,726      uops_retired_all          # 5381.779 M/sec                    ( +-  0.01% )
     2,018,126,488      uops_retired_retire_slots # 3425.680 M/sec                    ( +-  0.01% )
     1,491,267,343      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   72.11% frontend cycles idle     ( +-  0.66% )
        27,192,780      stalled-cycles-backend    #    1.31% backend  cycles idle     ( +- 68.75% )

       0.589651097 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  1.32% )
```

It's very unusual to see uops_dispatched_thread not matching uops_retired_all.  They're usually both the same, and equal to the number of unfused uops for instructions in the loop.  Fused-domain uops_issued_any and uops_retired_retire_slots are usually both equal, which they are in this case.  Maybe memory-destination ALU ops count differently in dispatched vs. retired_all?  (micro-fusion).  I think my previous testing has only [looked at micro-fusion of loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes/31027695#31027695).

I don't think it's issuing uops that turn out not to be needed.  (It's not a branch-mispredict issue; I checked, and both versions have 0.00% branch mispredicts.  (only ~10k for 288M branches).)

```
## CODE2 ##
peter@tesla:~/src/SO$ ocperf.py stat -r4 -e task-clock,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_dispatched.thread,uops_retired.all,uops_retired.retire_slots,stalled-cycles-frontend,stalled-cycles-backend ./a.out 2
perf stat -r4 -e task-clock,cycles,instructions,cpu/event=0xe,umask=0x1,name=uops_issued_any/,cpu/event=0xb1,umask=0x1,name=uops_dispatched_thread/,cpu/event=0xc2,umask=0x1,name=uops_retired_all/,cpu/event=0xc2,umask=0x2,name=uops_retired_retire_slots/,stalled-cycles-frontend,stalled-cycles-backend ./a.out 2
CODE2: ts: 16499
CODE2: ts: 16535
CODE2: ts: 16517
CODE2: ts: 16529

 Performance counter stats for './a.out 2' (4 runs):

        543.886795      task-clock (msec)         #    0.999 CPUs utilized            ( +-  1.01% )
     2,007,623,288      cycles                    #    3.691 GHz                      ( +-  0.01% )
     5,185,222,133      instructions              #    2.58  insns per cycle        
                                                  #    0.11  stalled cycles per insn  ( +-  0.00% )
     5,474,164,892      uops_issued_any           # 10064.898 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
     7,586,159,182      uops_dispatched_thread    # 13948.048 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
     6,626,044,316      uops_retired_all          # 12182.764 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
     5,473,742,754      uops_retired_retire_slots # 10064.121 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
       566,873,826      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   28.24% frontend cycles idle     ( +-  0.03% )
         3,744,569      stalled-cycles-backend    #    0.19% backend  cycles idle     ( +-  2.32% )

       0.544190971 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  1.01% )
```

In the fused-domain, issued & retired_slots match for CODE2.

Comment: I know this 2.5 years old, but very, very recently, LLVM 7.0.0svn added a tool called [`llvm-exegesis`](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-exegesis.html) that could help a lot for this and other questions.