# Time performance SIMD assembly programs: longer loop executes faster

Tags: loops, assembly, time, simd

I have recently been learning about SIMD in assembly (x86_64), and had some unexpected results. What it comes down to is the following.

I have two programs that run through a loop a number of times. The first program contains a loop that executes 4 SIMD instructions, the second contains this exact same loop with one extra instruction. The codes look like this:

The first program:

```
section .bss
doublestorage: resb 8

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 0x0000000100000001
    mov [doublestorage], rax
    cvtpi2pd xmm1, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm2, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm3, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm4, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm5, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm6, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm7, [doublestorage]

    mov rax, (1 << 31)
loop:
    movupd xmm1, xmm3
    movupd xmm2, xmm5
    divpd xmm1, xmm2
    addpd xmm4, xmm1
    dec rax
    jnz loop

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

The second program:

```
section .bss
doublestorage: resb 8

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 0x0000000100000001
    mov [doublestorage], rax
    cvtpi2pd xmm1, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm2, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm3, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm4, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm5, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm6, [doublestorage]
    cvtpi2pd xmm7, [doublestorage]

    mov rax, (1 << 31)
loop:
    movupd xmm1, xmm3
    movupd xmm2, xmm5
    divpd xmm1, xmm2
    addpd xmm4, xmm1
    movupd xmm6, xmm7
    dec rax
    jnz loop

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Now, my line of thought was the following: the second program has more instructions to execute, so it will take considerably longer to execute. If I time both programs, though, the second program turns out to take less time to complete than the first program. I ran both programs a total number of 100 times, and the results are:

```
Runtime first program: mean: 5.6129 s, standard deviation: 0.0156 s
Runtime second program: mean: 5.5056 s, standard deviation: 0.0147 s
```

I conclude that the second program runs considerably *faster*. These results seem counterintuitive to me, so I was wondering what could be the reason for this behavior.

To be complete, I am running Ubuntu 15.10 and the NASM compiler (-elf64) and using an Intel Core i7-5600. Also, I checked the disassembly and no optimizations had been made by the compiler:

Objdump of the first program:

```
exec/instr4:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000004000b0 <.text>:
  4000b0:   48 b8 01 00 00 00 01    movabs $0x100000001,%rax
  4000b7:   00 00 00 
  4000ba:   48 89 04 25 28 01 60    mov    %rax,0x600128
  4000c1:   00 
  4000c2:   66 0f 2a 0c 25 28 01    cvtpi2pd 0x600128,%xmm1
  4000c9:   60 00 
  4000cb:   66 0f 2a 14 25 28 01    cvtpi2pd 0x600128,%xmm2
  4000d2:   60 00 
  4000d4:   66 0f 2a 1c 25 28 01    cvtpi2pd 0x600128,%xmm3
  4000db:   60 00 
  4000dd:   66 0f 2a 24 25 28 01    cvtpi2pd 0x600128,%xmm4
  4000e4:   60 00 
  4000e6:   66 0f 2a 2c 25 28 01    cvtpi2pd 0x600128,%xmm5
  4000ed:   60 00 
  4000ef:   66 0f 2a 34 25 28 01    cvtpi2pd 0x600128,%xmm6
  4000f6:   60 00 
  4000f8:   66 0f 2a 3c 25 28 01    cvtpi2pd 0x600128,%xmm7
  4000ff:   60 00 
  400101:   b8 00 00 00 80          mov    $0x80000000,%eax
  400106:   66 0f 10 cb             movupd %xmm3,%xmm1
  40010a:   66 0f 10 d5             movupd %xmm5,%xmm2
  40010e:   66 0f 5e ca             divpd  %xmm2,%xmm1
  400112:   66 0f 58 e1             addpd  %xmm1,%xmm4
  400116:   48 ff c8                dec    %rax
  400119:   75 eb                   jne    0x400106
  40011b:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
  400120:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  400125:   0f 05                   syscall
```

Objdump of the second program:

```
exec/instr5:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000004000b0 <.text>:
  4000b0:   48 b8 01 00 00 00 01    movabs $0x100000001,%rax
  4000b7:   00 00 00 
  4000ba:   48 89 04 25 2c 01 60    mov    %rax,0x60012c
  4000c1:   00 
  4000c2:   66 0f 2a 0c 25 2c 01    cvtpi2pd 0x60012c,%xmm1
  4000c9:   60 00 
  4000cb:   66 0f 2a 14 25 2c 01    cvtpi2pd 0x60012c,%xmm2
  4000d2:   60 00 
  4000d4:   66 0f 2a 1c 25 2c 01    cvtpi2pd 0x60012c,%xmm3
  4000db:   60 00 
  4000dd:   66 0f 2a 24 25 2c 01    cvtpi2pd 0x60012c,%xmm4
  4000e4:   60 00 
  4000e6:   66 0f 2a 2c 25 2c 01    cvtpi2pd 0x60012c,%xmm5
  4000ed:   60 00 
  4000ef:   66 0f 2a 34 25 2c 01    cvtpi2pd 0x60012c,%xmm6
  4000f6:   60 00 
  4000f8:   66 0f 2a 3c 25 2c 01    cvtpi2pd 0x60012c,%xmm7
  4000ff:   60 00 
  400101:   b8 00 00 00 80          mov    $0x80000000,%eax
  400106:   66 0f 10 cb             movupd %xmm3,%xmm1
  40010a:   66 0f 10 d5             movupd %xmm5,%xmm2
  40010e:   66 0f 5e ca             divpd  %xmm2,%xmm1
  400112:   66 0f 58 e1             addpd  %xmm1,%xmm4
  400116:   66 0f 10 f7             movupd %xmm7,%xmm6
  40011a:   48 ff c8                dec    %rax
  40011d:   75 e7                   jne    0x400106
  40011f:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
  400124:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  400129:   0f 05                   syscall
```

Comment: There can be data dependency. The time is bound by div unit, but in the first loop the divisor is constant. Some constants (subnormals) may execute much slower.

Comment: You'd better have a statistically significant sample if you want to discuss 0.6% performance difference.

Comment: The additional instruction can be performed at the same time as everything else in the loop — I'd dare expect it to add zero cost simply because now the processor gets to use an arithmetic unit for a cycle that it otherwise wasn't using it for. So same speed isn't surprising; faster is a surprise unless you've just happened somehow to make the processor sufficiently confident about another out-of-order opportunity where before it wasn't certain. Those decisions have a time cost ceiling so are often broad phase only.

Comment: @Aki Suihkonen That doesn't seem to be the whole answer. Even if I initialize the xmm registers to the same values and replace the instruction I add by one that doesn't influence the others, I obtain a similar behavior. I'll update the question elaborating.

Comment: @EOF You're right, I'll take a statistical sample and update the results in the question.

Comment: @Tommy It turns out that on my system the second program does execute faster indeed.

Comment: Could you `objdump` the executables? I wonder if there could be an issue with macro-op fusion of the `dec; jnz`-pair if they are in different 16-byte aligned blocks.

Comment: @EOF Alright, I'll add them to the question too.

Comment: Well, there goes that idea. I don't see any obvious dependency/out-of-order explanations for this. There are a few esoteric issues like micro-op caches or loop-buffers that *could* explain this, but that's rather involved.

Comment: @EOF Ok, welk thanks for having a look anyway. I am setting all xmm registers to 1 though right? That way I tried to avoid dividing by 0.

Comment: Yeah, I was confused about the contents of the `doublestorage`. Anyway, AFAIK there's a tool Intel provides to analyze the cycle-exact execution of such code snippets.

Comment: @EOF That looks like a good option. I'll have a look into it, thanks!

Comment: IACA only supports up to Haswell.  It doesn't say anything other than 14c per iteration for both loops, bottlenecking on divider throughput.  (Agner Fog's measurements for `divpd` are one per 8-14c throughput on Haswell, one per 8c on Broadwell .)  There was [a recent question about broadwell throughput](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309707/significant-fma-performance-anomaly-experienced-in-the-intel-broadwell-processor), but that's about saturating the frontend.  Possibly one of the `movupd` insns isn't being eliminated, and is stealing p0 from `divpd` for a cycle sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

There's [no such thing as an "i7 5600"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadwell_(microarchitecture)#Mobile_processors).  I assume you mean [i7 5600U](http://ark.intel.com/products/85215), which is a low-power (15W TDO) CPU with 2.6GHz base / 3.2GHz turbo.

Can you double-check that this is reproducible?  Make sure CPU clock speed stays constant across both tests, because your low-power CPU may not be able to run at full turbo with the divide unit busy all the time.

Maybe also useful to test with perf counters (e.g. `perf stat ./a.out`), measuring core clock cycles.  (*not* "reference" cycles.  You want to count actual cycles that the clock is actually running at.)

---

[IACA](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer) only supports up to Haswell.  It doesn't say anything other than 14c per iteration for both loops, bottlenecking on divider throughput.  (Agner Fog's measurements for `divpd` are [one per 8-14c throughput on Haswell, one per 8c on Broadwell](http://agner.org/optimize/).)

There was [a recent question about broadwell throughput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309707/significant-fma-performance-anomaly-experienced-in-the-intel-broadwell-processor), but that's about saturating the frontend.

---

This loop should be purely bottlenecked on `divpd` throughput ([one per 8c on Broadwell](http://agner.org/optimize/)).  If the effect is real, the only explanation I've come up with is that one of the `movupd` insns isn't always being eliminated, and is stealing p0 from `divpd` for a cycle sometimes.

The three unfused-domain uops in the loop all run on different ports, so there's no way they can delay each other.  (`divpd` on p0, `addpd` on p1, and predicted-taken fused `cmp/jcc` on p6).

Actually, even that theory doesn't hold water.  Non-eliminated `movaps xmm,xmm` use port 5 on Broadwell.  I assume the odd choice of `movupd xmm,xmm` also decodes to a port5 uop.  (Agner Fog doesn't even list an entry for the reg-reg form of `movups`/`movupd`, because everyone always uses `movaps`.  Or `movapd` if they like matching insn type to the data, even though it's a byte longer and no existing uarch cares about `s` vs `d` for bypass delays, only `movaps` for float/double and `movdqa` for integer.)

---

Interestingly, my 2.4GHz E6600 (Conroe/merom microarch) runs your loop in 4.5s.  Agner Fog's tables list `divpd` on Merom as one per 5-31c.  `1.0/1.0` presumably happens in 5c.  Sandybridge has significantly slower best-case divide than Nehalem.  It's only with Skylake that the best-case throughputs are down as fast as Merom.  (Throughput fixed at one per 4c for 128b `divpd`).

---

BTW, here's a version of your code that uses a couple more normal ways to set up FP data in regs:

```
    default REL              ;  use RIP-relative for access to globals by default, so you don't have to write `[rel my_global]`

section .rodata
    ; ALIGN 16               ; only desirable if we're doing a 128b load instead of a 64b broadcast-load
one_dp: dq   1.0

section .text

global _start
_start:
    mov      rax, 0x0000000100000001
    mov      [rsp-16], rax     ; if you're going to store/reload, use the stack for scratch space, not a static location that will probably cache-miss.
    cvtpi2pd xmm1, [rsp-16]    ; this is the form with xmm, mm/m64 args.   Interestingly, for the memory operand form, this should perform the same but saves a byte in the encoding.
    cvtdq2pd xmm8, [rsp-16]    ; this is the "normal" insn, with  xmm, xmm/m64 args.
    movq     xmm9, rax
    cvtdq2pd xmm9, xmm9
    ; Fun fact: 64bit int <-> FP is only available for scalar until AVX-512 introduces packed conversions for qword integer vectors.

    ;mov      eax, 1      ; still 1 from earlier
    cvtsi2sd xmm2, eax
    unpcklpd xmm2, xmm2   ; broadcast

    pcmpeqw  xmm3,xmm3          ; generate the constant on the fly, from Agner Fog's asm guide
    psllq    xmm3, 54
    psrlq    xmm3, 2            ; (double)1.0 in both halves.

    movaps   xmm4, xmm3         ; duplicate the data instead of re-doing the conversion.  Shorter and cheaper.
    movaps   xmm5, xmm3
    movaps   xmm6, xmm3

    ;movaps   xmm7, [ones]      ; load 128b constant
    movddup   xmm7, [one_dp]        ; broadcast-load 

    mov eax, (1 << 31)          ; 1<<31 fits in a 32bit reg just fine.
;IACA_start
.loop:
    ;movupd   xmm1, xmm3
    ;movupd   xmm2, xmm5
    movaps   xmm1, xmm3      ; prob. no perf diff, but weird to see movupd used for reg-reg moves
    movaps   xmm2, xmm5
    divpd    xmm1, xmm2
    addpd    xmm4, xmm1
    ;movaps  xmm6, xmm7
    dec      eax
    jnz    .loop
;IACA_end

    mov eax, 60
    xor edi,edi
    syscall                     ; exit(0)
```

For IACA, I used:

```
%macro  IACA_start 0
     mov ebx, 111
     db 0x64, 0x67, 0x90
%endmacro
%macro  IACA_end 0
     mov ebx, 222
     db 0x64, 0x67, 0x90
%endmacro
```

---

#### Did you try stripping the loop down even more?

```
.loop:
    movapd   xmm1, xmm3       ; replace the only operand that div writes
    divpd    xmm1, xmm2
    addpd    xmm4, xmm1
    dec      eax
    jnz    .loop
```

Then the loop is only 4 fused-domain uops.  Should make zero difference, since `divpd` throughput should still be the only bottleneck.

Or with AVX:

```
    vdivpd    xmm0, xmm1, xmm2
    vaddpd    xmm4, xmm4, xmm0
    cmp/jcc
```

Comment: You're right, I'm using the i7-5600U.
Secondly, I did another simulation today and alternated the first and second program in an attempt to reduce any unwanted effects. The results were similar: `5.5282 +/- 0.0094` vs. `5.4285 +/- 0.0092`, indicating that the second program is indeed faster.

Comment: Stripping the loop down by removing the `movapd xmm2, xmm5` instruction resulted in more logical results, it caused the second program to run a little bit slower than the first, which sounds reasonable. Furthermore, changing to `movapd` or `movaps` does not seem to influence the timing significantly.

Comment: @arriopolis: saving a byte with movaps instead of movapd will make zero difference, since the loop executes from the loop buffer.  It doesn't have to be decoded every iteration.  The code-size benefit is just for overall code size / L1 cache size in the big picture of the program you might use this code in.  Also, removing `movapd xmm2,xmm5` shouldn't have any effect on the timing either.  The expected result is that the loop runs at one iteration per 8 cycles, up to the point where there are enough other insns to be a bottleneck (which is nowhere near happening here).

Comment: @arriopolis: With [`ocperf.py`](http://halobates.de/blog/p/245), have a look at the perf counters for `uops_dispatched.port0` or whatever the exact name of that counter is, and see if there are more uops being issued to p0 than just the divide.  (AFK several hours)

Comment: Well it looks like removing the `movapd xmm2, xmm5` actually did influence the timing, as <i>with</i> the extra move, the second program executes faster, and <i>without</i> it, the first program executes faster.